# Странное поведение тега img

Tags: html, img

Вот заметил одну вещь:
 1. имеем простой тег img
 2. если вставить в строку два тега с бордером=0, то они будут впритык друг к другу.  Пример:

```
    <img src="pict.jpg"><img src="pict.jpg">
```

1. А если разделить энтером

   ```
   <img src="pict.jpg">
   <img src="pict.jpg">
   ```

то между ними появляется пробел ровно в 3 px.
Почему происходит такое странное явление, ведь энтер неотображаемый символ.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Кто вам сказал, что перенос строки неотображаемый? Как раз очень даже.
Чтобы избежать того, что случилось у вас, закомментируйте перенос строки.

```
   <img src="pict.jpg"><!--
--><img src="pict.jpg">
```

Comment: Спасибо! Гениально! :)
Это уже из разряда хаков.

Answer (score 4):

Давайте, попробую рассказать с другой стороны
img - очень интересный тэг; ведёт себя одновременно как блок и как строка.
если родительскому элементу прописать css правило line-height:0;, вертикального пробела не будет

Comment: Как-то не сработало на img

Answer (score 1):

Вообще, **img** - это **инлайновый (строковый) элемент**, поэтому он и ведет себя как простой текст.
Если написать элементы **img** без пробела/переноса строки, то изображения будут идти впритык друг к другу.

Конечно, для удобства чтения кода, лучше писать с переносом строки, в этом случае, чтобы избежать нежелательных пробелов, **можно воспользоваться следующими решениями:**

1. **img { float: left; }**
2. для родительского элемента задать:  **word-spacing: 0;**
3. **воспользоваться комментариями**, как посоветовал [[@knes](/users/2825/knes)](/users/2825/knes).

Удачи

Comment: Спасибо, на досуге попробую.